# How to debug Azure Data Factory V2 Invalid Trigger Type?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I created a new ADF V2 pipleline with a tumbling window trigger via powershell.  When starting the pipeline I get an error:

```
Start-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name "DailyTriggerCookForecastPipeline"

[ERROR] Start-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger : HTTP Status Code: BadRequest
[ERROR] Error Code: BadRequest
[ERROR] Error Message: Invalid trigger type: Trigger
[ERROR] Request Id: 6591ae6b-902d-4b25-9f62-c6bb67796d57
[ERROR] Timestamp (Utc):01/08/2018 16:05:30
[ERROR] At line:1 char:1
[ERROR] + Start-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup - ...
[ERROR] + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ERROR]     + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Start-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger], ErrorResponseException
[ERROR]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.StartAzureDataFactoryTriggerCommand
[ERROR]
```

My trigger is defined as:

```
{
  "name": "DailyTriggerCookForecastPipeline",
  "properties": {
    "type": "TumblingWindowTrigger",
    "typeProperties": {
      "frequency": "Hour",
      "interval": "24",
      "startTime": "2018-01-01T04:00:00Z",
      "retryPolicy": {
        "count": 2,
        "intervalInSeconds": 30
      },
      "maxConcurrency": 1
    },
    "pipeline": {
      "pipelineReference": {
        "type": "PipelineReference",
        "referenceName": "CookForecastPipeline"
      },
      "parameters": {
        "SliceStart": "@trigger().outputs.windowStartTime"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have no idea how to debug this further.  Is there a way to get a more detailed error message?  I couldn't find one in the portal.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding -Verbose at the end of the command? For some commands it adds more detail to the error message.

Comment: I just did, it didn't get me any other info regarding the error though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Martin suggested in the comments a good first step is to add -verbose flag.  Unfortunately it doesn't add much info.

The second step for debugging is to make sure your setup is correct.  In this case it turned out that TumblingWindowTrigger was just released but I had an older SDK.  This dependency wasn't documented anywhere.  So turns out the errors are pretty accurate.